# Python3.6 to exe or compile to other option?

Tags: python, exe, python-3.6

Im desperately trying to compile my python 3.6 script to an exe or any executable file that i can share to other without showing my source code. I have try cx_freeze, py2exe, pyinstaller etc etc but non of them support python3.6.

So, any alternative out there or i can simply install python 2.7/3.5 (in order to use any compiler mention above)? will that work?

Comment: http://pypy.org/ woks well. Not sure what platform you are on. I've only used it on linux and osx.

Comment: If you do not use specific functionalities that were added in 3.6 you can easly just use 3.5 to create executable file. If you do use that you can use dev version of pyinstaller which will work for most part with 3.6 except several third party modules that have not yet been updated to work with 3.6.

Comment: i am on windows

Answer (score 1):

PyInstaller has development version that currently works with python 3.6, however the installation isn't as simple as with pip (how it should work at the end). You will most likely be able to just download python 3.5 and use any of the tools on it.

Installing PyInstaller from a source code (on windows):

Download developer version from the web --> http://www.pyinstaller.org/downloads.html
Unpack it - both zip and tar are archives
Open command line and get into the main directory, named something like this: "pyinstaller-pyinstaller-89dc7eb"

next run this command in the command line:

```
python setup.py install
```

that should run and when it finishes, just enter

```
pyinstaller
```

and if you don't get any errors you should be all good to go

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i tried this and it successfully created an exe file.. but when i click it, nth happen, it came out a window and close automatically. May i know where i did wrong? i follow all the steps

Comment: Depends, by default it should open command line and keep it while the exe is running, it might be that it finishes immediately (No wait nor while loop)

Comment: it works but do you know how to freeze the screen after i input my answer? cause it automatically close the output window when i type in my answer/when the programs end. How do i let the window stay open?

Comment: your easiest way may be to do `os.system('pause')` that will display the typical "Press any key to continue..." when used on windows and wait for the keypress